# how to set a timer for button in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer

I am new to react-native.I need to show a button only for 30 minutes.I don't have a clear solution on the internet about timers,any help would be appreciated.
How do I set timers for a button to show only for 30 minutes & hide after it?

Comment: check out [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function to control the visibility of the Button.

**Sample code**:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isButtonVisible: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isButtonVisible: false });
    }, 1000 * 60 * 30);
  }

  render() {
    const { isButtonVisible } = this.state;
    return (;
      <View>
        ...
        {
          isButtonVisible && <Button .../>
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

You could follow this for how to make a countdown. A crude approach would be to make your component stateful and keep track of the time. If the time is 30 minutes or over use a ternary to change the view and hide the button.